# Facebook keeps deleting my application

Tags: php, facebook

FB keeps deleting my application. I am thinking that the likely problem is that we allow users to share their score result with their friends, i.e. the user can select group of people who are also in the same group, and the script will post on all of their walls. I don't think that app is acting in any way not in accordance with FB policy. My guess instead is that due to relatively high amounts of requests to post feed [some users can select 100 and more friends]. Can it be so? Is there a way to post multiple feeds in single request, in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/policy_checklist/

Ensure that the application "does not provide users with the option to publish more than one Stream story at a time."

The behavior that Facebook wants you to use is that a user posts something on his own profile to share it with multiple people. Posting the same story on multiple profiles at once is contrary to how the social channels are meant to be used.